# How do I determine the maven coordinates of this jar in a local lib directory?

Tags: java, maven, build, jar

I'm new to maven and am converting a java web app to maven (instead of managed by my IDE). I understand that can install the dependency locally (first choice) or declare it as a provided dependency (second choice). [I read about](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) what `groupId`, `artifactId`, and `version` mean. However, it doesn't explain how to determine the exact coordinates of a jar.

[The jar in question (servlet-api.jar of apache-tomcat 7.0.34)](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.34/) for example, doesn't have a pom.xml file in the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a random jar file, in this case servlet-api.jar, present in some folder, you have to poke around to figure out if it is the same as some version.

**One**:Look inside the jar and note the date (or date range) of the files inside it. You might notice what files are in there. You might need that detail.

**Two**: Go to somewhere that you can look for the jar. I like http://mvnrepository.com/ where you can type in the name of the jar. "servlet-api". I found this one in about 10 seconds:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifact>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.36</version>
</dependency>
```

But its not yours. (Another 30 seconds and I found this: [mvnrepository servlet-api for tomcat 7.0.34](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.34))

- You can then download the one you think matches and look inside it to see if the date matches.
- Its basically detective work from here. You might find the exact jar with maven 'coordinates' and you might not.

Reading the other answers reminded me that with the Java EE jars, I find it best to use a generic version for building your application. Use "provided" for the maven scope. The the container will provide the real jar and, if it isn't totally standard, you won't be using the non-standard parts because your build used the generic version.

So, for example, you might build with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I typically do is go to http://search.maven.org and look for the jars, for example: servlet-api.jar. You can also do fully qualified class name search, eg if you know inside your jar there is a class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, you can search for **fc:javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest** and it will list all jars containing this class

However keep in mind in the case of servlet-api.jar -- it shouldn't be bundled into your war/ears because it should be provided by container (tomcat in this case). Typically the best practice when creating Java EE project is to include dependency to javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5 (or other version supported by you container) in **provided** scope. Hence the jars will only exist in your classpath during compile time, but at runtime it will be provided by the container

Answer (score 0):

The Maven artifacts (JAR files) will be located in e.g.

```
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/artifact/version/
```

The servlet-api.jar file will be located in ~/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/ if I remember correctly - given that you use version 2.5 of the servlet specification.

However, the servlet-api is always provided by the application container, hence the "provided" type of the dependency in the Maven POM.